# C++ program that starts another program (client-server)

Tags: c++, sockets, cross-platform, boost-asio

I need to write two C++ programs that communicate with each other bidirectionally via sockets and one program starts the other. This project needs to be cross-platform. I've done some research and concluded that it'll be best to use boost::asio for the sockets part, but I'm not exactly sure how I should start the other process. There are many ways to do this (for example: https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044654269&id=1043284392), but I'm not sure which one would suit my needs. I thought the `spawn` function should be fine here, but I can't get it to work (the compiler can't find the process.h file).

Do you have any tips regarding this particular problem? Is  `spawn` indeed the right solution here or should I try something else?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Boost.Interprocess yet?

Comment: Haven't heard of it to be honest. Thanks, I'll be looking it up now

Comment: Hmm I meant to write Boost.Process actually, which should help you along quite a bit. Interprocess could replace/implement your plans with sockets, but Process actually answers your question I think.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to confirm if process.h exists in any of your include paths.If it doesn't, provide your compiler with an include directory which contains process.h .
That may mean you have to search for process.h in your system; begin with the gcc/g++/mingw include directories.